# Playing the beep in SO chat

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chat

I am trying to play the notification beep (or mention beep) in the SO chat using a Chrome extension, but I cannot get it right (if it is even possible). I have tried the following code:

```
this.notify = function () {
  $("#jplayer").jPlayer('play', 0);
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jPlayer'

Is there a way to use the SO chat sound 'module' / player to play the @mention beep?

**UPDATE**

I know I can setup my own 'audio player', but I want to use the audio player that is used in the chat here on SO and I want to to use the notification beep.

I've uploaded my full code in a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/2003746) which is part of [this project](https://github.com/PeeHaa/cv-pls). The line where I am trying to call the audio player is [224](https://gist.github.com/2003746#L224).

Comment: In what file did you put this code? I'm guessing the code isn't being run on the page, but rather the background page for the extension.

Comment: @Walkerneo I'm running this in one of the "content_scripts" JS files.

Comment: @Walkerneo I added a link to the project so you can verify.

Comment: I gave you a working example that met your criteria, why no tick?

Comment: Your profile page said you had been, but what ever it doesnt matter, glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a sandbox thing I guess, your not allowed to execute scripts from the page so i guess plugins count to.
That known its just a matter of playing outside the sandbox....

**script.js**

```
var customEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
customEvent.initEvent('JPlayerNotify', true, true);

function notify() {
    document.getElementById('communicationDIV').innerText='notify';
    document.getElementById('communicationDIV').dispatchEvent(customEvent);
}

// Utitlity function to append some js into the page, so it runs in the context of the page
function appendScript(file) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src", chrome.extension.getURL(file));
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}

appendScript("JPlayer.js");

// had to wait for a bit for the page to be ready (dialup and all), you wont need to do the setTimeout
setTimeout("notify()",3500);
```

**JPlayer.js**

```
var notify_node = document.createElement('div');
notify_node.id = 'communicationDIV';
document.documentElement.appendChild(notify_node);

notify_node.addEventListener('JPlayerNotify', function() {
  var eventData = notify_node.innerText;
  if (eventData=='notify'){
    $("#jplayer").jPlayer('play', 0);
  }
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "JPlayerNotify",
  "version": "0.5.0",
  "description": "JPlayerNotify",
  "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches": ["http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/*"],
      "js" : ["script.js"],
      "run_at" : "document_idle",
      "all_frames" : false
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "http://stackoverflow.com/*",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/*",
    "http://*.stackoverflow.com/*",
    "https://*.stackoverflow.com/*"
  ]
}
```

You can see some stuff on communicating with the page here...  http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
new Audio('beep.wav').play();
```

Chrome has Audio support (recent versions anyway), so this should be just fine. This is what I use in my extension.

Comment: Fair enough, that's your prerogative. But this way works, and is simple. Do you have a link to any documentation for this SO chat module so I can try to help answer your question?

Comment: I've updated a link in my question to the full code. There are no docs for the functionality because it is SO chat internal.

Comment: To extend on this... how about... `new Audio(chrome.extension.getURL("so.mp3")).play();` and so.mp3 comes from http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/so.mp3

Comment: @PAEz well... now we are getting closer. Maybe I should just forget about it and do it this way. But still I would like to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Its a sandbox security thing...check my answer, you can use JPlayer if you want.